Excel VBA dependent drop down lists with a twist
A user has asked for a change to a macro.  In column 26, I have a drop down list with 6 options: (A, B, C, D, E, and F).
The user would like a drop down list in column 2 with 3 options (1, 2, and 3); if column 26 has Option A, C, E, of F.  There should be no drop down list if Option B of D is selected.
In the past, I have created 1 drop down list if the the Country was US and a 2nd drop down list if the Country was CA.  US and CA were the only 2 choices.
I'm kind of stumped of how to proceed with this scenario.
thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.......

Here is what I tried. I based the column 26 dropdown by selecting the horizontal list next to "choices" (see image below). Then I used the following formula to conditional create the dropdown for column 2. If value "B" or "D" is selected then the list of horizontal choices for that row are empty. Otherwise all the choices show up. The dropdown is still there either way, but the dropdown has no choices for B or D. Take note that for the dropdown source for column 2 I have removed the dollar sign before the row number in the list formulas (see image) so the dropdown is based on that row.
This is the formula for the various choices rows.
=IFS($I6="",Q$4,$I6="B","",$I6="D","",TRUE,Q$4)




